# Flutter Time sensitive Notification

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created app to app calling APP using FCM where I need to do

- Voice calling
- Chat messaging

For chat messaging I am able to show flutter local notification and on tapping of it navigating to chat screen.

Problem is when I need to call I wanted to show sensitive Notification like whats app and telegram and I don't want to tap notification.

Call is only work when APP is in **FOREGROUND** but not in **BACKGROUND**

Comment: I am also searching for that. Did you got any solution?

Comment: @prabhur Not yet But For this one workaround can be writing Native Code and calling it through Method channel in Flutter

Comment: I got the solution and I implemented also in my app. Do you need the solution?

Comment: Please provide so every one will get benifited

Comment: Solution I used : Implement fcm in native side and listen for messages in native, and display time-sensitive notification using native method. You can also  send broadcast when you receive fcm and write receiver action in ur app.